# iOS - Keychain - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, entitlements

When installing my app on my device I get the error:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements
>
> The entitlements specified in your application's Code Signing Entitlements file are
> invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your
> provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)

I have a valid "Entitlements.plist" file. If I remove the "Keychain" entitlement from the file it installs **successfully**.

My Keychain entitlement looks like:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>com.MyCompany.MyApp</string>
</array>
```

My Bundle identifier and AppID is similar to:

> com.MyCompany.MyApp

My AppID for the provisioning profile looks like this:
[image: AppID]

How do I enable Keychain withing the provisioning profile? Or what am I missing from the Entitlements file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer: http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/

You need to add your prefix to the app string so it looks like:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>AppPrefix.com.MyCompany.MyApp</string>
</array>
```

Comment: How do I know what my AppPrefix is?

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 In your screenshot you provided you censored the bit in red. The prefix should be a alphanumeric string

Comment: if that didn't help, check out step 5 in http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/